# I am getting an error integrity constraint violation 1052 column invoice_no in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, eloquent

My Query as mention i know that this error comes when alias or table not added with the column  name.but i am not able to figure out which line is having that error.

```
  $receipts = Receipt::where(["receipts.workshop_id" => Auth::user()->workshop_id])
    ->leftJoin("invoices", "invoices.invoice_no", "=", "receipts.invoice_no")
    ->join("customers", "customers.id", "=", "invoices.inv_customer_id")
    ->select("receipts.id as iid", "receipts.*", "customers.customer_name as customer_name", "invoices.status as inv_status")
    ->whereIn("receipts.invoice_format", ['', 'Main Invoice', 'TML Invoice', 'General Invoice']);
```

Comment: I do not see any `WHERE` clause with `invoice_no` in what you've posted, so that does not appear to be the correct query?

Comment: Dear Paul In ther 4th line wherein is mention after select statement

Comment: That's not sql code so what is it?

Comment: It's an sql query, and the language used is php laravel feom where we are calling our table that is receipt an applying inner joi or left join to get the record from multiple tsble

Comment: Ok, so where is `invoice_no` found in this part of that query: `whereIn("receipts.invoice_format", ['', 'Main Invoice', 'TML Invoice', 'General Invoice']);`? ... so again, this does not look to be the correct query based on the error message.